# Laravel + AngularJS controller is existing but returns an error of not a function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

Im just new to AngularJS and would like to integrate it using Laravel (5.2)
I was able to successfully load Laravel and Angular in this manner.

HTML File: `../resources/views/master.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/phone-app/app.module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="todoApp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Todo</h2>
                <div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
                    <span>{{todoList.remaining()}} of {{todoList.todos.length}} remaining</span>
                    [ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]
                    <ul class="unstyled">
                        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
                        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AngularJS File: `../public/assets/js/phone-app/app.module.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('todoApp', [])
        .controller('TodoListController', function() {
        var todoList = this;
        todoList.todos = [
          {text:'learn angular', done:true},
          {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

        todoList.addTodo = function() {
          todoList.todos.push({text:todoList.todoText, done:false});
          todoList.todoText = '';
        };

        todoList.remaining = function() {
          var count = 0;
          angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
          });
          return count;
        };

        todoList.archive = function() {
          var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
          todoList.todos = [];
          angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
            if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
          });
        };
    });
})();
```

But when I created a separate html that will accommodate angular templates, this is when I get an error of `Argument 'TodoListController' is not a function, got undefined`

Here's the structure:

HTML File: `../resources/views/master.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/phone-app/app.module.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="todoApp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <todo-app></todo-app>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AngularJS File: `../public/assets/js/phone-app/app.module.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('todoApp', []);

    angular.module('todoApp')
        .component('todoApp', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/js/phone-app/templates/todo.html',
            controller: function TodoListController() {
                var todoList = this;
                todoList.todos = [
                    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
                    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

                todoList.addTodo = function() {
                    todoList.todos.push({text:todoList.todoText, done:false});
                    todoList.todoText = '';
                };

                todoList.remaining = function() {
                    var count = 0;
                    angular.forEach(todoList.todos, function(todo) {
                        count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
                    });
                    return count;
                };

                todoList.archive = function() {
                    var oldTodos = todoList.todos;
                    todoList.todos = [];
                    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
                        if (!todo.done) todoList.todos.push(todo);
                    });
                };
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

Template File: `../public/assets/js/phone-app/templates/todo.html`

```
<h2>Todo</h2>
<div ng-controller="TodoListController as todoList">
    <span>{{todoList.remaining()}} of {{todoList.todos.length}} remaining</span>
    [ <a href="" ng-click="todoList.archive()">archive</a> ]
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="todoList.addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoList.todoText"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</div>
```

If you'll notice, I moved the content on a separate template file. This loads the page with the template but returns an error on the console and just displays the page as is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this work but somehow don't know how this works. @_@
Anyway, I just tried to search for examples on the AngularJS site and tried to "copy" them. With that, I have arrived with this solution.

On the template file, I removed the `ng-controller` and change all the `todoList` with `$ctrl`.

```
<h2>Todo</h2>
<div>
    <span>{{$ctrl.remaining()}} of {{$ctrl.todos.length}} remaining</span>
    [ <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.archive()">archive</a> ]
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in $ctrl.todos">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.addTodo()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.todoText"  size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</div>
```

Will someone please explain to me how did the `$ctrl` worked in here and why the ng-controller is not necessary in this kind of structure versus the first one I stated above?

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
.component
```

with

```
.directive
```

Maybe components have a bug

Comment: I doesn't work :( I was able to find the solution to my answer but I needed a clear explanation on how it worked since I just copied it other sites.